# Applying Superposition principle - Hayt fig 5.7

Tags: superposition

Here is my problem from Hayt
[image: Fig 5.7]

I am trying to solve applying superposition principle, but I am not getting anywhere close to the correct answer.

As the first step I eliminated 2A current source. [image: omit 2A]

I tried to solve it using mesh analysis. In the first loop I introduced clockwise current called i_1, in the second loop I introduced clockwise current called i_2. Here are the equations that I wrote for it.

-3 + 7i_1+15i_1 + 5(i_1-i_2) = 0

i_2 = -4i

i_1-i_2 = i

I solved it and got i = -1/61 and v_2 = -5/61 which is far off from stated answer: -0.246V

What did I miss?

Then I short-circuited 3V voltage source:

[image: Omit 3V]

I solved it using node analysis. Nodes are labelled in the main picture. Here are my equations:

2= v_1/7 + (v_1 + v_2)/15

4i = (v_2 - v_1)/15 + v_2/5

v_2 = 5i

I solved it and got v_2 = -546, which is again far off from -1.148.

I double checked my calculations. Could somebody confirm that I got correct equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the answer below.Do not kill dependent sources while applying SPST.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I found my computational error. I did not kill dependent source. It is present in my system (i_2 = -4i). I like how you express current in terms of dependent current source.

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

In your mesh equations, you wrote i_1-i_2 = i.  I think you meant i_2-i_1 = i.  Your diagram didn't clearly show the directions of i_1 and i_2, so you made it hard for yourself to debug your own equations.  I infer their directions from the two loop equations.

You appear to have declared the current from the dependent source to be 0 A.  This is not valid unless current *i* is 0 A.  When using superposition the procedure calls for killing *independent* sources, not *dependent* sources.

Comment: Thank you! I should have created better diagram. I should have added arrow indicating i_1 and i_2 direction instead of writing that they are clockwise. 0A dependent source is just artifact of multisim diagram, I had to put some value there. So I have chosen 0A, but  I am not using this value anywhere.